# Angular material, the requested path contains undefined segment at index 1

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I just finished an Angular course and a couple of YouTube tutorials, and I'm trying to make my own web app by combining what I learned. So I'm utilizing Angular Material table and attempting to navigate using an ID on the selected row, but I've run into the following error:

> The requested path contains undefined segment at index 1

and If I click the first button which leads to the detail component, the localhost path says undefined

> http://localhost:4200/detail/undefined

I checked similar problems but I didn't manage to fix it. Any suggestions or tips to fix this?

Here's my HTML:

```html
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    <!-- ID Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = dataIndex;" > {{i+1}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
     <!-- First Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="firstName">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> First Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.firstName}}</td>
    </ng-container>
  
     <!-- Last Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="lastName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Last Name </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.lastName}} </td>
     </ng-container>
  
     <!-- Email Column -->
     <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Email </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.email}} </td>
     </ng-container>
  
     <!-- Mobile Column -->
     <ng-container matColumnDef="mobile">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Mobile </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.mobile}} </td>
    </ng-container>

      <!-- BMI Result Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="bmiResult">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> BMI </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.bmiResult}} </td>
    </ng-container>

     <!-- Gender Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="gender">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Gender </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.gender}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Membership Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="membership">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Membership </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.membership}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Start Date Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="startDate">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Start Date </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.startDate | date}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Action Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Action </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> 
      <button mat-button color="warn" [routerLink]="['/detail', row.id]"><mat-icon>remove_red_eye</mat-icon></button>
      <button mat-button color="accent" (click)="edit(row.id)"><mat-icon > border_color</mat-icon></button> 
      <button mat-button color="primary"><mat-icon>delete_forever</mat-icon></button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
```

My component:

```js
public users!: User[];
public dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<User>;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) matsort!: MatSort;
displayedColumns: any[] = ['id','firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'mobile', 'bmiResult', 
  'gender', 'membership', 'startDate', 'action']

constructor(private api: ApiService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit() {
  this.getUsers()
}
getUsers(){

this.api.getRegisteredUser().subscribe(result => { 
  if (Array.isArray(result)) { 
    this.users = result; 
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users); 
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator; 
    this.dataSource.sort = this.matsort; 
    } else { 
    console.error("Received data is not an array:", result); 
    } 
  }); 
}
applyFilter(event: Event) {
  const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
  this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

  if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
    this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
  }
}
edit(id: number){
  this.router.navigate(['update', id])
  }
}
```

My routes:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'register', pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: 'register', component: CreateRegistrationComponent },
    { path: 'list', component: RegistrationListComponent },
    { path: 'detail/:id', component: UserDetailComponent },
    { path: 'update/:id', component: CreateRegistrationComponent },
];
```

Comment: Sandoy, have you a property "id" in the elements of your array? Actually you're using `{{i+1}}` in your code to show a "id".

Comment: Data I received from the server don't have an ID so I'm using let i = dataIndex to fill the table with ID.

Comment: Then use the same in "action td":`<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;let i=dataIndex"><button mat-button color="warn" [routerLink]="['/detail', (i+1)]">`

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. I changed it to "let i = index" since the "i=dataIndex" is NaN. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you have to put your button code inside below code of block:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="action">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action</th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <button mat-button color="warn" [routerLink]="['/detail', row.id]">
        <button mat-button color="accent" (click)="edit(row.id)">
       </td>
</ng-container>
```

will work as expected for you. This error occur because when you define button control there are no any `row` element available so you need to use `row` element and then assign value.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I do have that on my HTML, I posted the button only for shorter question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: give full code of block. in your code i feel error is because of row is not define

Comment: posted my entire HTML file. I am so confused on where is my error.

Answer (score 0):

> The requested path contains undefined segment at index 1

This tells you that somewhere there's an undefined passed somewhere at index 1. This is also what your url route shows: /detail/undefined when in your router outlet you defined it like /detail/:id . So you need to investigate your router.navigate[...], specifically what you pass as index 1.
you only use it in a button in your template and there is your issue -> row.id is undefined.

When passing row.id to something in the frontend it needs to be wrapped by something like

```
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> ... </td>
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I only posted the button earlier for a shorter question. I did wrapped it when passing the row.id

Comment: well you can still try to investigate the cause by looking at what value is passed to your router navigate because I still believe my explanation is most likely correct with all the other information you posted.